# Hardcoded Credentials for Dynamodb AWS Queries

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a script which checks if a specific value is inside a cell in a dynamodb table in AWS. I used to add hardcoded credentials containing the secret key in my script such as this:

```
dynamodb_session = Session(aws_access_key_id='access_key_id',
          aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key',
          region_name='region')

dynamodb = dynamodb_session.resource('dynamodb')

table=dynamodb.Table('table_name')
```

Are there any other ways to use those credentials without adding them to my script ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running that code on an Amazon EC2 instance, then you simply need to **assign an IAM Role to the instance** and it will automatically receive credentials.

If you are running that code on your own computer, then use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command to store the credentials in a local configuration file. (It will be stored in `~/.aws/credentials`).

Then, in both cases, you can simply use:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
```

You can set the default region in that configuration too.